# Can the beginning of a cavity be halted in its tracks

Tags: dentistry

Is there a way to stop the beginning of a cavity from progressing into a bigger one? Is that even possible for the start of a cavity of a bottom wisdom tooth under the gums of a partly erupted wisdom tooth?